# String stream in haskell

Tags: haskell, stream, char

I am trying to create this stream  `l = ["","a","aa","aaa",...]` in haskell.

Can someone help me?

Comment: using iterate: `iterate ('a':) []`

Answer (score 6):

Combine inits with repeat:

```
λ: let l = inits $ repeat 'a'
λ: take 10 l
["","a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aaaaa","aaaaaa","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaa"]
```

Answer (score 6):

We can get there just by iteratively consing elements onto the empty list using

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

by just doing

```
iterate ('a':) ""
```

Comment: This is also more memory-efficient than the other approaches. We all want our toy examples to be as efficient as possible, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
[replicate i 'a' | i <- [0..]]
```

This isn't exactly advanced stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Without using predefined functions:

```
l = l' ""
    where l' s = s : l' ('a':s)
```